# How to send dictionary context while returning a redirect function to get context data when calling this function from an api?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have a function which redirect to a url, this function have a context dict. I want to get this dict by calling this function from another api function call.

Web function:

```
def myfunction(request, id):
    context = dict()
    obj = Model.objects.get(id=id)
    obj.status = 'Draft'
    obj.save()
    # Success Message to Mobile App
    context['status'] = 'Success'
    context['message'] = 'Reset successfully'
    context['d'] = id
    context['Number'] = obj.no  # I want to attach this context in return (not in the url like 
                                # kwargs or args but separately) so that I get context
                                # when I call this function from another function
    return redirect('del_details',str(id))
```

API calling function

```
class CallingAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def post(self, request):
      
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       
        try:
            response = function1(request=request, id=serializer.data['id'])
            # here in response I want the context from function1
            json_response = json.loads(response.content)
            if json_response['status'] == 'success':
                # Do something
                return JsonResponse(final_result, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
           
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

So when I do response = function1(request=request, id=serializer.data['id']), I want the context dictionary in response and redirect will remain same. How to achieve it? Right now I am getting only `<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/del_details/120/"` in response, I need the context data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a seperate function where you can keep the common functionality. Then use it from both Web View and API View. Like this:

```
def some_function(id):
    """
    Here I am adding the common codes which will be used by both myfunction and CallingAPI view.
    """
    context = dict()
    obj = Model.objects.get(id=id)
    obj.status = 'Draft'
    obj.save()
    # Success Message to Mobile App
    context['status'] = 'Success'
    context['message'] = 'Reset successfully'
    context['d'] = id
    context['Number'] = obj.no
    return context

def myfunction(request, id):
   context = some_function(id)
   return redirect('del_details', str(id))


class CallingAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def post(self, request):
      
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = some_function(serializer.data['id'])
        # rest of the code
```

Comment: Yes, but requirement is to use only one function for both web and api, is there any way to achieve it , please  suggest

Comment: You can use a boolean value to do that.

Comment: You can make a alternative solution, like with GET request make the redirection with overriding the `get()` method in CallingAPI view, and `post()` to send context like current implementation